# como mostrar a traves de find(), eventos por region

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose, find

Un colega me dijo que estaba mandando mal la query en el Event.find(), pero no se si hay algo más que estoy haciendo mal. Este codigo es parte del llamado de todos los eventos, de mi archivo events.database.ts
Tengo base de datos MongoDB.

```
const getEvents = async (sortBy: string, sortOrder: string, skip: number, limit: number, upcomingEvents: boolean, region?: string): Promise<IEvent[]> => {
    try {
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const sortOrderOption = sortOrder === 'asc' ? 1 : -1 || 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
        const sortCompi: any = {};
        sortCompi[sortBy] = sortOrderOption;
        const query: any = {};
        const place: any = {};
        if (upcomingEvents) {
            query.eventDate = { $gte: currentDate };
        }
         console.log(place)
        const events: IEvent[] = await Event.find( query, { createdAt: 0, updatedAt: 0 })
            .sort(sortCompi)
            .skip(skip)
            .limit(limit);
        return events;
    } catch (e: any) {
        console.log(e)
        throw e;
    }
};
```

Esta es mi coleccion de region, la cual tiene id, country, region y communes, ya que estoy haciendo un filtro de busqueda, que filtre eventos por region y comuna dentro de Chile.

```
{
        "country": "Chile",
        "region": "Arica y Parinacota",
        "communes": [
            {
                "name": "Arica"
            },
            {
                "name": "Camarones"
            },
            {
                "name": "Putre"
            },
            {
                "name": "General Lagos"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Este es uno de los eventos.

```
{
    "name": "Adan y Eva",
    "description": "Representacion artistica " ,
    "eventDate": "2023-07-28T23:30:08.893Z",
    "eventType": "teatro",
    "place": "Nacimiento",
    "address": "Anibal pinto 556, Casa de la Cultura",
    "capacity": 500,
    "region":"Arica y Parinacota"
}
```